# Bug: I can't save my document after running this code

Tags: vba, excel

I've breaking my head over this. After running this quote, which I've written to fix some issues with worksheets, I can't save my document anymore. I don't understand what's causing the problem. Does anybody have an idea?

```
Dim c As Range
Set c = Sheets("Accounts").Range("B3")
Dim wsOld As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
Dim strNameID As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do Until c.value = ""

        'Correct Name ID
        strNameID = UCase(Left(c.value, 4)) & Right(c.value, 4)
        Sheets(c.value).Name = strNameID
        c.value = strNameID

        If c.Offset(0, 1).value <> "" Then
            'Set old WS
            Set wsOld = Sheets(c.Offset(0, 1).value)

            'Set new WS
            Sheets("TemplateINT").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Set wsNew = Sheets("TemplateINT (2)")

            'Copy values
            wsNew.Range("C2:L100").value = wsOld.Range("C2:L100").value

            'Delete old WS
            wsOld.Delete

            'Rename new WS
            wsNew.Name = c.Offset(0, 1).value

            'Correct column AC
            c.Offset(0, 27).value = "='" & c.Offset(0, 1).value & "'!C4"

        End If

        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)

    Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set c = Nothing
Set wsOld = Nothing
Set wsNew = Nothing
```

Everytime I try to save the document after running this code, Excel tells me:

"Errors were detected while saving *Document x*. Microsoft Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make the repairs in a new file, click continue. To cancel saving the file, click cancel."

Continue doesn't change anything.

Comment: My usually debugging suggestion for something like this is to comment lines of code until the issue disappears. Then let us know what line is giving you grief

Comment: In addition to Cody's suggestion, I further suggest doing this first with one worksheet to copy & process.

Comment: What version of Excel? How many worksheets in your file?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, guys. Unfortunately I still can't find the problem. With one worksheet it works fine, but it seems there is a problem in the loop. I've tried to dim i as integer and adjust the loop to `Do Until c.value = "" And i > 1` and add a `i=i+1` to the loop. This should run the loop 2 times, but it runs it until c.value="".

Comment: Excel 2010 and there are over 100 worksheets in the file. Nevertheless only 29 should be replaced.

Comment: Never mind my earlier comment. I should have used Or instead of And in the loop statement.

Comment: It seems to be a rather random error. I still don't know what it was, but having my document saving itself in every loop and adding the row number of c in a seperate cell, I found that the code stopped working at random numbers. I "solved" it by closing the document once an error occurred and changed the starting cell of c once I reopened the document and continued from there. It's not a good solution, I know, but I only had to run this code once, so I guess it will do. Thanks for your help!